# Why does my UIButton Stay In Selected State?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit

Many of the questions here ask how to make a button stay selected, I'm asking why does my button stay selected, and how to remove this? I created a custom UIView class programmically added a UIButton as follows.

```
 // Toolbar
 UIView *toolbar                 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 33.0f)];
 toolbar.backgroundColor         = [UIColor colorWithRed: 238.0/255.0f green: 238.0/255.0f blue: 238.0/255.0f alpha:1];
    _button                = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(263.0f, 3.0f, 37.0f, 30.0f)];
 // Create button
 [_button setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 _button.titleLabel.font          = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
 _button.titleLabel.textColor     =  [UIColor colorWithRed:92.0/255.0f green:92.0/255.0f blue:92.0/255.0f alpha:1];
 [_button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


  [toolbar addSubview:_button]

// Add toolbar to UIView class
 [self addSubview:toolbar];
```

When the button is clicked on the toolbar, it turns from black to white and stays white. Why is this?

Comment: Can you post the implementation of `btnPressed:` ? May be some time consuming process on button action is going on.

Comment: What is your button regular mode color? And what is the selected color?

Comment: I commented out everything in btnPressed: so assumed there's nothing happening there. The only color I set is in the code above where I have the line _button.titleLabel.textColor.